# Errores al usar los setters Python

Tags: python, poo

Buenas estoy intentando resolver el siguiente ejercicio usando la Programación Orientada de Objetos en Python, al ejecutarlo todas las funciones me van menos los setter, ¿alguien sabe porque falla?.

Enunciado: Clase que almacena duraciones de tiempo. Los objetos de esta clase son intervalos de tiempo y se crean de la forma:

- t1 = Duration(1, 20, 30)  # almacenará 1 hora, 20 minutos y 30 segundos.
- t2 = Duration(2, 75, -10)  # almacenará 3 horas, 14 minutos y 50 segundos.
- t3 = Duration(t2)  # almacenará las horas, minutos y segundos del objeto t2
  Tiene getters y setters mediante propiedades y métodos para:
- Sumar y restar objetos de la clase (el resultado es otro objeto).
- Sumar y restar segundos, minutos o horas (se cambia el objeto actual).
- Devolver una cadena con el tiempo almacenado, de forma que si lo que hay es (10 35 5) la cadena sea '10h 35m 5s'

Este es el código:

```
from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked class Duration:
    def __init__(self, hour, min=None, sec=None):
        if isinstance(hour, Duration):
            time = hour
            self.__hour, self.__min, self.__sec = time.hour, time.min, time.sec
        elif isinstance(hour, int) and isinstance(min, int) and isinstance(sec, int):
            self.__hour = hour
            self.__min = min
            self.__sec = sec
            self.__normalizar()
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Error, datos introducidos no válidos.')

    def __normalizar(self):
        seconds = self.__hour * 3600 + self.__min * 60 + self.__sec
        if seconds < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Error: El tiempo total en segundos debe ser mayor que 0.')
        self.__hour = seconds // 3600
        self.__min = seconds % 3600 // 60
        self.__sec = seconds % 3600 % 60

    @property
    def hour(self):
        return self.__hour

    @hour.setter
    def hour(self, value: int):
        new_duration = Duration(value, self.__min, self.__sec)
        self.__hour, self.__min, self.__sec = new_duration.hour, new_duration.min, new_duration.sec

    @property
    def min(self):
        return self.__min

    @min.setter
    def min(self, value: int):
        new_duration = self.__hour, value, self.__min
        self.__hour, self.__min, self.__sec = new_duration

    @property
    def sec(self):
        return self.__sec

    @sec.setter
    def sec(self, value: int):
        new_duration = self.__hour, self.__min, value
        self.__hour, self.__min, self.__sec = new_duration

    def sub_sec(self, seconds: int):
        self.__sec -= seconds
        self.__normalizar()

    def add_sec(self, seconds: int):
        self.__sec += seconds
        self.__normalizar()

    def sub_min(self, minutes: int):
        self.__min -= minutes
        self.__normalizar()

    def add_min(self, minutes: int):
        self.__min += minutes
        self.__normalizar()

    def sub_hours(self, hours: int):
        self.__hour -= hours
        self.__normalizar()

    def add_hours(self, hours: int):
        self.__hour += hours
        self.__normalizar()

    def __add__(self, other: 'Duration'):
        return Duration(self.__hour + other.__hour, self.__min + other.__min, self.__sec + other.__sec)

    def __sub__(self, other: 'Duration'):
        return Duration(self.__hour - other.__hour, self.__min - other.__min, self.__sec - other.__sec)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__hour}h: {self.__min}m: {self.__sec}s.'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}: {self.__hour}: {self.__min}: {self.__sec}.'
```

[image: imagen de ide]

Como veis en la imagen intento cambiar las horas usando el setter creado y me encuentro con un error de tipo.

Comment: Las propiedades te permiten ejecutar una función al acceder via atributo. Es decir a.b, siendo b una propiedad, es equivalente a a.b(), siendo b una función. En resumen, las propiedades no se llaman ni se les pasan argumentos

Comment: Como la propiedad hour te devuelve un entero, Python intenta llamar dicho entero y falla.

Comment: El setter funciona asignandole un valor a la propiedad: a.b = 0 por ejemplo.

Comment: El código está bien, como te dijeron, estás intentando ejecutar una propiedad agregándole `()`. Simplemente quita los paréntesis y funciona: `d1.hour`. Por otro lado, tienes un argumento `min=None`. Esto sobreescribirá la funcion `min()` de Python, y si la necesitas te va a salir el error: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`. Recomiendo cambiar ese nombre para conservar la [funcionalidad built-in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).